# Using Python for Random Number Generation Based on Percent Chance

Tags: python, random

I have an appliance that operates in two states - on and off.

Between a certain time period in a day (say 6am to 8pm), it has 5% chance of being on and 95% chance of being off.

Between the remaining time period (8pm to 6am), it has 75% chance of being on.

If the output is an array of `1`s and `0`s and is 8,760 rows long (for each hour of the year), how do I use a random number generator in Python to generate a time series of on/off states for a year?

Comment: How long will the array be -- how long does the appliance stay in its same state?

Comment: The array is supposed to be 8760 points long (hours in a year)

Comment: In your question you speak of a week, while in comments you speak of a year. Which of the two you are looking for?

Comment: My apologies, it is a year long. I have edited my question.

Comment: How will you deal with leap years, and daylight saving?

Comment: @LevuPanda, there're two answers and you haven't reacted to any of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like `int(random.random() <= 0.75)`. It will return `1` 75% of the time and `0` otherwise. For example:

```
import random
from datetime import datetime

if 6 < datetime.now().hour < 20:
    print(int(random.random() <= 0.05))
else:
    print(int(random.random() <= 0.75))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) with `weights` argument:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from random import choices

if 6 < datetime.now().hour < 20:
    weights = 95, 5   # 95% - False (Off), 5% - True (On)
else:
    weights = 25, 75  # 25% - False (Off), 75% - True (On)

state = bool(choices(range(2), weights=weights)[0])
```

Or you can write the same in one-liner

```py
state = bool(choices(range(2), weights=(95, 5) if 6 < datetime.now().hour < 20 else (25, 75))[0])
```

**Upd.**

From updated question it became clear that you need to generate list for each hour for entire year.

**Code:**

```py
from calendar import isleap
from random import choices

year = 2021
states = []

for _ in range(365 + isleap(year)):  # iterate over days
    for i in range(24):              # iterate over hours
        if 8 < i < 20:
            states += choices(range(2), weights=(95, 5))
        else:
            states += choices(range(2), weights=(25, 75))

# OR one-liner

states = [choices(range(2), weights=(95, 5) if 6 < i < 20 else (25, 75))[0] for i in range(24) for _ in range(365 + isleap(year))]
```